# Show Day and Date as rows in php weekly calendar

Tags: php, html

I have a weekly calendar that Im trying to set the day and date as rows but it doesn't seem to line up correctly.

[image]

```
<?php
$dt = new DateTime;
if (isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['week'])) {
    $dt->setISODate($_GET['year'], $_GET['week']);
} else {
    $dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W'));
}
$year = $dt->format('o');
$week = $dt->format('W');
?>

<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week-1).'&year='.$year; ?>">Pre Week</a> <!--Previous week-->
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week+1).'&year='.$year; ?>">Next Week</a> <!--Next week-->

<table>

<?php
do {
    echo "<tr>" . $dt->format('l') . "<br>" . $dt->format('d M Y') . "</tr>\n";
    $dt->modify('+1 day');
} while ($week == $dt->format('W'));
?>
</table>
```

I'm pretty new to php and any type of web development so any help would be great

Also any pointers on grouping data based on those day rows would be awesome as well.

Comment: I think you forgot to insert `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

you are using a break line `<br>` between the day and the date, as you are using a table you should use the `<td>...</td>`

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $dt->format('l') . "</td><td>" . $dt->format('d M Y') . "</td></tr>\n";
```